# WCF service not showing the methods and variables

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have written WCF service and published on IIS. When I try to access wsdl of the WCF service by using **?wsdl** it is not showing the method names that I have declared in WCF service. but if I use **?wsdl=wsdl0** it shows the method definitions and all other data. Why?

Also, I have tried almost all the suggestions provided in the other possibly duplicate threads but that didn't work for me.

**Interface class:**

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:x.ServiceContracts",  Name = "xService", SessionMode = System.ServiceModel.SessionMode.Allowed, ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None)]
public partial interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(IsTerminating = false, IsInitiating = true, IsOneWay = false, AsyncPattern = false, Action = "Insert", ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None)]
    string[] Insert(string name);
```

In config file I have added below to expose the methods still it doesn't worked for me.

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Can anyone tell me what I have missed?

Comment: If you're running on .NET 4.5 or higher, you could also use `?singleWsdl` to get the entire WSDL and XSD in a single file

Comment: @marc_s I am using .NET 3.5 and cannot use higher version ! :(